# Action sheet getting caught on tabbar

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet, tabbar

This is a tricky one that I've been working on for a while. I have a an action sheet that appears in a view with a tabbar, sometimes when I dismiss the action sheet it gets "caught" in the tabbar and am unable to do anything.The app doesn't crash because if i minimize it and then come back in it is dimissed, it just appears that the modal behavior isn't being dismissed properly.

I recently changed how the action sheet is displayed from "showInView" to "showFromTabBar" and am not sure if this is creating the issue.

Thanks,
  William

Edit:

Below is the code I use to dismiss my actionsheet:

```
-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{



    if ([[self viewWithTag:1] isKindOfClass:[PickerView class]]) {

        PickerView *picker = (PickerView *)[self viewWithTag:1];

        if (picker.selectedRow == nil) {
            [picker populateSelectRowForRow:0 andComponent:0];
        }

        NSNotification *note = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"doneButtonPressed" object:self.indexPath userInfo:picker.selectedRow];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];

    }else {

        DatePickerView *picker = (DatePickerView *)[self viewWithTag:1];

        NSDictionary *extraInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[self formatDateToString:[picker date]], nil] forKeys:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"value", nil]];

        NSNotification *note = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"doneButtonPressed" object:self.indexPath userInfo:extraInfo];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];
    }


    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

and the notification method that is called:

```
-(void)pickerUpdate:(NSNotification *)note{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [note object];
    NSDictionary *extraInfo = [note userInfo];

    NSDictionary *dict = [[tableController.sectionAndFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row + kHeaderAndFooterOffset)];

    [tableController.formDetails setObject:[extraInfo objectForKey:@"value"] forKey:[dict objectForKey:@"key"]];

    NSArray *reloadArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
    [indexPath release];

    [self.tv reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:reloadArray withRowAnimation:NO];
    [reloadArray release];


}
```

Comment: Can you please include some code / a screenshot to help visualizing your problem?

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are showing and dismissing the action sheet?

Comment: the second parameter of `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` is not a `BOOL`; it is a `UITableViewRowAnimation` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to solve this however it feels very much like a hack, I introduced a delay into the code using:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(dismissFromActionSheet) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
```

With dismissFromActionSheet being:

```
-(void)dismissFromActionSheet{
 [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```